# java - OCR with Asprise library

Tags: java, android, bitmap, ocr

I make an Android app that captures a photo and saves the text from it using OCR. This is my code with Asprise library, but something is wrong with the "recognize" method:

```
Ocr.setUp();
Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST);
String s = ocr.recognize(theImage, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
ocr.stopEngine();
```

"theImage" is Bitmap, but they want "RenderedImage" type there (thought Bitmap is rendered too), and the fourth parameter of the "recognize" method is "Object... propSpec", but there in the sample of asprise official site there are only 3 parameters. And now parameters in the "recognize" line are underlined with red. So, what should I do with my code that it work properly?

P.S. Of course, I've heard about tess-two library, but it's a bit complicated for me to add it in Android Studio (I don't know why they couldn't just make it the way that it be added with only one line in build.gradle)

Answer (score 0):

I've implemented same , what you want to do , by following code , and this is working as i wanted it to , other issues may be like file reader in your PC i.e, if you want PDF file to be OCR , .pdf reader should be installed .

```
   Ocr.setUp();
   Ocr ocr = new Ocr();
   ocr.startEngine("eng", Ocr.SPEED_FASTEST);
   String s = ocr.recognize(new File[] {new File(path)},
   Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
   System.out.println("Result: \n" + s);
   ocr.stopEngine();
   System.out.println("---END---");
```

Comment: The problem is that I need to run this OCR on my Android phone and I need to pass just captured Bitmap. Maybe, I can save this Bitmap on my phone and than put that path from phone memory into your code...what's the working way to do it?